# Use Redux without npm

Tags: javascript, redux

I am trying to use Redux in a project without using npm.

I have tried:
`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>`
but don't know what global variable it creates (`redux` is not defined).

I have also tried using `import { createStore } from "https://unpkg.com/redux@4.0.5/dist/redux.js";` which says `Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module 'https://unpkg.com/redux@4.0.5/dist/redux.js' does not provide an export named 'createStore'`

How can I use Redux with either a script tag or http import?

Comment: the question can be more general, like, `how to use a package without npm / webpack?`

but I believe this can help. https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/examples/counter-vanilla/index.html

you might just use `Redux` instead of `redux`

Comment: @tim thanks! This worked, so I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from Tim's comment:

`<script src="https://unpkg.com/redux@latest/dist/redux.min.js"></script>`

`let store = Redux.createStore(counter);`